# the best way to create many new pages with php

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to import data from foreign database tables in TYPO3 and create hundreds of pages with content from this data. The data is good structured so I could map most fields with simple SQL. How would it be possible to achieve this with TYPO3 9.5. Any hint where to look for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is there since "ever" and is called DataHandler.
see docs at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html

Comment: "formerly known as TCE" :-) thanks, that was exactly what i am looking for!

Answer (score -1):

I know you could achieve this with the `external_import` extension.

See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/external_import/Index.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds interesting, i will take a look.